# Irreducibility of set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a subset of the topological space $X$ and let $\{U_i\}$ be an open cover of $X$.

1.If $Y$ is not contained in any $U_i$ then $Y$ is irreducible?

2.If $\{V_j\}$ is an open cover of $Y$ which has no pair of disjoint $V_j,V_k$, then $Y$ is irreducible??

Comment: Both answers are negative. An example that works for both is $Y=[1,2]\cup[3,4]$, $X=[0,4]$, $U_1=[0,2]$, $U_2=(2,4]$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that your hypotheses are wrong. Since Hausdorff spaces with more than one element are never irreducible, you can find easy counterexamples using subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, for example using a covering by the sets $(n,n+2)$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for 1, and all of $X$ for 2.

Check your hypotheses.

Comment: That is a true or false question.. what does it mean to say hypothesis is wrong?

Comment: That the question is unlikely to be asked in this form.

Comment: thanks. If $X$ is not Hausdorff, is it true?